# How to rename a project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

This has been asked and answered, but the answers appear not to be relevant to the current Visual Studio 2017 Preview edition. How can you change the target name in a project? I don't much care what the .sln name is, but I do want the application to be named appropriately. Earlier answers point to the Application line in the project properties, which doesn't exist in VS 2017. An answer for VS 2017 suggests changing the applicationhost.config file, which appears not to exist in my project. But surely there is some way to change the name of an app under development? Thanks... [Update: it's a C++/winrt uwp project]

Comment: This depends on the project type. The steps are different for a classic Desktop Win32 application, a WPF application, or a UWP application. Please include information on the project type in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer this myself - the difference from earlier versions appears to be this: to change the display name of the app, open the package.appxmanifest in Solution Explorer. There you find the Application category that apparently was in the Properties window in earlier versions. Changing the solution name, etc. is something I don't dare attempt, but this is enough.